# Query node information from PeerId only

Tags: substrate-node-template, networking, libp2p, peers

How do I get Listen addresses of a node (and possibly other info like agent, protocols etc..) given that I only have node's `PeerId`? Is there any existing solutions available for this? Simple enter `PeerId` -> get all node info.

I found libp2p-lookup tool but it is working with full addresses only it seems.